# Работает ли defineProperty с неконфигурируемыми свойствами?

Tags: javascript, объекты

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/property-descriptors#flagi-svoystv)

> configurable – если true, свойство можно удалить, а **атрибуты можно изменять, иначе этого делать нельзя.**

Получается, что `configurable` со значением `false` запрещает удалять св-во и изменять его атрибуты.

Хорошо, с удалением все работает как надо, но вот атрибуты можно изменить и со значением `false`.

```js
let obj = {
    name: 'Eva',
    greeting () {
        return this.name;
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'greeting', {
    configurable: false //нет возможности удалить св-во, изменять атрибуты
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'greeting', {
    writable: false //изменение атрибута
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'greeting')); //writable false
```

Как так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это исключение, прописанное в спецификации. Для неконфигурируемых свойств можно сменить `writable` c `true` на `false`, но не наоборот, то есть вернуть потом не получится. Логика в том, что можно усилить защиту свойства, но не ослабить её.

Вот [тут](https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/ch_property-attributes-intro.html#property-attributes) есть историческое объяснение:

> The rationale behind this anomaly is [historical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829817/why-can-i-set-enumerability-and-writability-of-unconfigurable-property-descrip/9843191#9843191): Property `.length` of Arrays has always been writable and non-configurable. Allowing its `writable` attribute to be changed enables us to freeze Arrays.